# Variables in PHP are lost after ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

My goal - take a payment through stripe or paypal, once it is complete, present the customer with a form to upload a file to send by email to me. My form is in a bootstrap modal. I am trying to ensure the form can't be submitted unless a payment is made.

The customer currently makes the payment, completed by ajax. This works fine, and is presented with a payment ID. However, when I send another ajax request to the same php document, to complete the email send, using `$send_form = $_POST["email_form"];`, the variable `$payment_made` has lost its value.

```
<?php
$send_form = $_POST["email_form"]; //this is sent by ajax. Will be 'yes' if the form to send has been submitted.

switch ($action){
  case 'stripe':
    //do stripe transaction
    //set a variable to indicate payment is complete using transaction ID
    $payment_made = $transaction->id;
  break;
  case 'paypal':
    //do paypal transaction
    //set a variable to indicate payment is complete using transaction ID
    $payment_made = $transaction->id;
  break;
}

function sendmail() {
  //usual php mail function (works fine)
}

if ($send_form = 'yes' && $payment_made != '') {
  sendmail();
}
?>
```

**My problem:** how do I use the `$payment_made` variable to verify a payment has been completed to prevent unauthorised use of the email form?

I won't upload the ajax or html code unless requested as it is all working correctly provided I don't check the `$payment_made` variable before using `phpmail()`.

Comment: how about storing the value in `session` and then checking for it by retrieving from the session. I presume that you have session working in your app

Comment: Every time you make an ajax request, you are running a new instance of your backend code. The only way for them to communicate is via Session storage or DB

Comment: Thanks, any chance of a quick example of session being used in this instance? Session is used in the stripe component already.

Comment: I put ``session_start();`` at the top of the document and I am able to pass the variable now. I put a session_unset(); and session_destroy(); below the sendmail(); function, but I am still able to access the session variable after a page reload. How do I fix that one?

Comment: Turns out I was using session_destroy(); in the wrong spot so it never ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Juakali92 and @alithedeveloper.

I used PHP sessions to store and then remove the variables.

```
<?php
session_start();
$send_form = $_POST["email_form"]; //this is sent by ajax. Will be 'yes' if the form to send has been submitted.

switch ($action){
  case 'stripe':
    //do stripe transaction
    //set a variable to indicate payment is complete using transaction ID
    $_SESSION["payment_made"] = $transaction->id;
  break;
  case 'paypal':
    //do paypal transaction
    //set a variable to indicate payment is complete using transaction ID
    $_SESSION["payment_made"] = $transaction->id;
  break;
}

function sendmail() {
  //usual php mail function (works fine)
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  mail();
}

if ($send_form = 'yes' && $_SESSION["payment_made"] != '') {
  sendmail(); 
}
?>
```